# Problems with doctrine in Symfony controller

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an error that I can find no solution. I have a driver Symfony this:

```
<?php

namespace Consolidador\PanelBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DataController extends Controller
{

    public function listOfUsers()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $settings = $em->getRepository('PanelBundle:Users')->findAll();

        return $settings;

    }

}
```

As seen only returns a list of users using Doctrine, well when I call on any method, like this:

```
    $users = new DataController();
    $listOfUsers = $users->listOfUsers()
```

An exception appears in the DataController class that has to do with Doctrine:

> Error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object

I do not understand what happens and I'm using and extending the controller so you should be able to access Doctrine without any error ... In other controllers use Doctrine without major problems.

Any solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you pass a doctrine reference to your class datacontroller? can you post the code of the datacontroller class?

Comment: The code DataController class is up. I do not refer in any way to Doctrine, are not you supposed that if you extend a class of Controller class can access the container dependency DIRECTLY, and hence Doctrine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the way you create instance of a class. A regular symfony controller instance is created by `service container` which calls `setContainer` method on it. Your `DataController` class has no knowledge about container and that's why you get an error (you can't just do `new DataController()`).

A quick and **dirty** way to solve this is just set container on your `DataController` instance:

```
$users = new DataController();
$users->setContainer($container); //you need to have container available, I don't know what context are you in
$listOfUsers = $users->listOfUsers();
```

A proper way to do this is to [define your Controller as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html), inject `Doctrine` into it and get it by

```
$dataController = $this->container->get('your_data_controller_class');
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: Other thing is that Controller is meant to take `Request`, and return `Response` object, in your case you are returning an array which is not good. You should move this logic somewhere outside Controller class - something like `UserManager` class. Then you should define this `UserManager` as a service, inject `Doctrine`, do your logic there and return data (an array). Than in your controller you should call this service.

This way you will get cleaner code and move logic outside of controller.

Comment: Thanks, I tried setting the container directly in the class and it worked. I will read the link you've passed me to do it as correctly as possible. THX!